# why this error is occuring Type mismatch: inferred type is HomeFragment but Context was expected

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to fetch API on recycler view of HomeFragment  using Kotlin I got this  error in my MySingleton file

```
class MySingleton constructor(context: Context) {

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MySingleton? = null
        fun getInstance(context: HomeFragment) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: MySingleton(context).also {
                    INSTANCE = it
                }
            }
    }

    private val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy {
        // applicationContext is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context.applicationContext)
    }
    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>) {
        requestQueue.add(req)
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly share your error

Answer (score 0):

You have to context as param type on `getInstance()`

Solution is :

```
  companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MySingleton? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: MySingleton(context).also {
                    INSTANCE = it
                }
            }
    }
```